# Facebook text is upside down

Tags: facebook

My facebook text is upside down. How do I fix it?

[image: screenshot of settings page]

Comment: I've just came across this ("English (uʍop əpısdՈ)" as an option in the language list), and thought it's a Stranger Things gag. Seeing the question is from 2013, it can't be. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you leave your computer unlocked at some point? Sounds like someone changed your language preference to English (Upside Down). Go to Settings > Language and select regular English to fix it.

Comment: Thanks I didnt even know that there is an option of upside down English.

Comment: Is there any particular reason of this upside down option in facebook

Comment: Because we're engineers, and we find it fun to build things like that.

Comment: yup may be that's the reason